# how to upload image Using multipart entity using retrofit in Android

Tags: android, retrofit

i am able to upload image using postman :

[image]

but when i tried using multi-part entity using retrofit i am not able to upload that it tell file is not find in server below is my code:

```
public void visitrecord_existingtask(int userId, String companyId, String taskId, String actionTaken, String timeSpend, double lat, double longi, ArrayList<String> filePaths) {
        MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
        builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
        builder.addFormDataPart("userid", String.valueOf(userId));
        builder.addFormDataPart("companyid", companyId);
        builder.addFormDataPart("taskid", taskId);
        builder.addFormDataPart("task_actiontaken", actionTaken);
        builder.addFormDataPart("timespent", timeSpend);
        builder.addFormDataPart("latitude", String.valueOf(lat));
        builder.addFormDataPart("longitude", String.valueOf(longi));
        for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.size(); i++) {
            File file = new File(filePaths.get(i));
            builder.addFormDataPart("files", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file));
        }
        MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();
        Call<VisitrecordExistingtask> call = webAPIInterface.visitrecordExistingtask(requestBody);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<VisitrecordExistingtask>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<VisitrecordExistingtask> call, Response<VisitrecordExistingtask> response) {
                visitrecordlistner.showLoginResult(response.code(), response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<VisitrecordExistingtask> call, Throwable t) {
                visitrecordlistner.showError(t);
            }
        });

    }
```

this is my code which i am using file upload to server  i have to send soem parameter plus image file to server but its not able to find image in server can any one please suggest me what i am doing wrong .

Comment: this ans will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866676/retrofit-uploading-multiple-images-to-a-single-key

Comment: do need to install one image..or multiple images?@Joan

Comment: @ AL Tegani  one image  only  i have to upload not multiple

Comment: @Joan i will modifiy your code to upload one image..but what is the purpose of this ArrayList<String> filePaths why list this against your needs??

Comment: we have to create some multiple file upload it i want to use it as reusable component

Comment: icould modifiy but without this ArrayList<String> filePaths

Comment: @ALTegani   ya please tell  me Solution how i will send image

Comment: @ALTegani are u there can you please tell me Solution for this .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167968/discussion-between-al-tegani-and-joan).