# How do I can upload multiple files and request body with retrofit?

Tags: android, http, retrofit

I get paths from picker. And then I need to upload this files and request body in one request body. It's like a post in the facebook(text, date, attachemnts etc.). How do I can do this with Retrofit?

Comment: Hey check out this two links you will get a clue of how to use it https://stackoverflow.com/a/48988861/6751183
and
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-a-dynamic-amount-of-files-to-server