# How to upload multiple images in android using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, image-upload

I want to upload three images using retrofit along with other text fields.How can I upload this and how can call the web service using retrofit?

Comment: Check this :https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-a-dynamic-amount-of-files-to-server

Comment: can you please specify the type of webservice endpoint you are using. Whether it accepts only one file or multiple files.This can help you to get specific answer. :)

Comment: I am using retrofit.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866676/retrofit-uploading-multiple-images-to-a-single-key)?

Comment: Api Service Interface:   
 @Multipart
    @POST("Edit_profile")
    Call<ResponseEditProfile>EditProfile(@Part("USERID") String userid,
                                         @Part("IMAGEONE\"; filename=\"myfile.jpg\" ") RequestBody imageone,
                                         @Part("IMAGETWO\"; filename=\"myfile.jpg\" ") RequestBody imagetwo,
                                         @Part("IMAGETHREE\"; filename=\"myfile.jpg\" ") RequestBody imagethree);

Comment: File fileone = new File(getfileonepath(fileoneUri));
        RequestBody requestFileone = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(fileoneUri)), fileone);

Comment: ApiServiceInterface apiServiceInteface=ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiServiceIterface.class);
        Call<ResponseEditProfile>usercall=apiServiceInteface.EditProfile(userid,requestFileone,requestFiletwo,requestFilethree);

Comment: This is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public interface UploadImages {  
    @Multipart
    @POST("upload_images")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadMultipleFiles(
            @Part("text") RequestBody text,
            @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> images);
}
```

OR

```
 @Multipart
 @POST("upload_images")
 Call<ResponseBody> uploadMultipleFiles(@Part("text") RequestBody text,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file1, 
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file2, 
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on [@Multipart](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Multipart.html) & [@Part](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Part.html) annotations documentation
They allow you to create a method like

```
@Multipart
@POST("/")
Call<ResponseBody> example(
    @Part("description") String description,
    @Part(value = "image", encoding = "8-bit") RequestBody image);
```

Which should do the thing for you.