# Sending multiple images using retrofit in a single key

Tags: java, android, file-upload, retrofit2

I have tried all the methods available on the internet but nothing is working for me.
I'm trying to send images in a Single Key Value

```
{
  files[]
}
```

This is my interface

```
public interface UserClient {
    @Multipart
    @POST(".")
    Call<JsonElement> upload(
            @Part("text") RequestBody text,
            @Part("image") RequestBody image,
            @Part("login") RequestBody login,
            @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> files
    );
}
```

this is my upload Method

```
public void uploadFiles(String text) {
    QBUser user = SharedPrefsHelper.getInstance().getQbUser();
    String userName = user.getFullName();
    String image = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/146/146031.svg";
    String URL = URLs.URL_POST + user.getPhone() + "/";

    RequestBody textPart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, text);
    RequestBody imagePart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, image);
    RequestBody loginPart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, userName);

    //list of files
    List<MultipartBody.Part> filesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList_FilePath.size(); i++) {
        filesList.add(prepareFilePart("files" + i, arrayList_FilePath.get(i)));
    }
    //Create retrofit instance
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    UserClient client = retrofit.create(UserClient.class);

    Log.i(TAG, "uploadFiles: " + filesList);
    Call<JsonElement> call = client.upload(textPart, imagePart, loginPart, filesList);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful: " + response.message(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body() + response.message());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

This is preparefilePart Method

```
public MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, String path){
    long imagename = System.currentTimeMillis();
    File file = new File(path);
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse("image/*"),
            file
    );
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, imagename + ".jpeg" ,requestBody);
}
```

If I send only text request without images its working fine but when i send image it's not working
it's giving an error Code 500 Internal Server Error with null response in body

Note: Api is working Great in Postman

[image: Postman Snipet]

Comment: this may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866676/retrofit-uploading-multiple-images-to-a-single-key

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology thanks but i have tried this answer it's not working for me

Comment: I'm getting Internal Server Error

Comment: then i think the issue in php file when you sending multiple files php will not handle that object properly

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology thanks dir for your Reply i have found the answer to my Question below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file was not uploading because file was not Creating Properly
thanks to github i found a way to create a file Properly

[GitHub link for creating file](https://gist.github.com/walkingError/915c73ae48882072dc0e8467a813046f)

Also Made a little bit of changes in my code according to this answer
[link for stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866676/retrofit-uploading-multiple-images-to-a-single-key)